# Modelica: assign array return value to scalars

Tags: algorithm, matrix, vector, modelica, dymola

The following model tries to assign a vector return value of a function call to a vector of scalars. It checks and works if it is inside an equation section, but it fails inside an algorithm section. Is that a bug in the Modelica tool I am using, or am I doing something wrong? And, how can I write it without introducing the intermediate variable x[2]?

```
model returnVector
  Real x1;
  Real x2;
  Real x[2];
  Real A[2,2] = [1,2;3,4];
  Real b[2] = {8,7};
algorithm 
  x = Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A,b);
  {x1, x2} = Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A,b);
end returnVector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something wrong :-)

In equations the left-hand-side is any expression; so you could even write `Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A,b)={x1,x2};`.

In algorithms the left-hand-side must be a component-reference (section 11.2 in Modelica 3.4; https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf ) and the right-hand-side is evaluated and then assigned to the left-hand-side variable.

Answer (score 1):

Under the 'algorithm', one must use ' := ' to represent the **Assignment** in Modelica instead of ' = ' as like in C/C++. 
So the code could be rewritten as follows:

```
model returnVector
  Real x1;
  Real x2;
  Real x[2];
  Real A[2,2] = [1, 2; 3, 4];
  Real b[2] = {8, 7};
algorithm 
  x := Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A, b);
  x1 := x[1];
  x2 := x[2];
  //{x1, x2} = Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A, b);
end returnVector;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the left-hand-side within round parentheses:

`({x1, x2}) := Modelica.Math.Matrices.solve(A, b);`

Comment: Please don't use this variant in algorithms. It should (and will in the future) generate similar error messages as in the question, and it may cause more subtle errors as well.